# Newest, unstable version of Ubuntu somehow appeared in my sources.list

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I used to use Ubuntu Trusty, on last Friday I started an "apt-get dist-upgrade" command.

And it was a disaster.

Almost everything stopped working.

It appeared that it tried (and failed) installing Ubuntu Xenial.

After opening etc/apt/sources.list it appeared that it was connected to "xenial" repos, as far as I understand this.

For example, there were lines looking like this one:

```
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted #Added by
software-properties
```

The question I have is: I'm 100% sure that I did not do it (intentionally), and nobody else did.

How could this happen? I mean, I know you can't know exactly what happened to me, but I'd like to know what are the possibilities.

I'm not good at Unix, actually I'm pretty bad, so I probably did a mistake somewhere, but this was the first time I discovered this word: "Xenial", so it's just impossible that I entered it.

Comment: Are you sure you did dist-upgrade and not do-release-upgrade ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes - I'm sure it was dist-upgrade.